wxglade does not work properly on Xubuntu 24.04LTS
Since upgrading to Xubuntu 24.04LTS, wxglade has not worked properly.
Here is the message.
➜  ~ wxglade
INFO    : Starting wxGlade version "1.0.5+repack" on Python 3.12.5
INFO    : Using wxPython 4.2.1
INFO    : Loading "wconfig" modules from /usr/share/wxglade/widgets/widgets.txt:
INFO    : Load code generators:
INFO    :   python generator loaded
INFO    :   perl generator loaded
INFO    :   lisp generator loaded
INFO    :   C++ generator loaded
INFO    :   XRC generator loaded
INFO    : Loading widgets from /usr/share/wxglade/widgets/widgets.txt:
INFO    :   frame
INFO    :   dialog
INFO    :   panel
INFO    :   notebook
INFO    :   splitter_window
INFO    :   button
INFO    :   toggle_button
INFO    :   bitmap_button
INFO    :   spin_button
INFO    :   text_ctrl
INFO    :   choice
INFO    :   combo_box
INFO    :   list_box
INFO    :   check_list_box
INFO    :   checkbox
INFO    :   radio_button
INFO    :   radio_box
INFO    :   spin_ctrl
INFO    :   spin_ctrl_double
INFO    :   slider
INFO    :   gauge
23時44分09秒: Debug: Adding duplicate image handler for 'Windows bitmap file'
23時44分09秒: Debug: Adding duplicate animation handler for '1' type
23時44分09秒: Debug: Adding duplicate animation handler for '2' type
INFO    :   calendar_ctrl
INFO    :   generic_calendar_ctrl
INFO    :   datepicker_ctrl
INFO    :   list_ctrl
INFO    :   tree_ctrl
INFO    :   grid
INFO    :   static_text
INFO    :   hyperlink_ctrl
INFO    :   static_line
INFO    :   static_bitmap
INFO    :   spacer
INFO    :   property_grid_manager
INFO    :   search_ctrl
INFO    :   custom_widget
INFO    :   menubar
INFO    :   toolbar
INFO    :   statusbar
INFO    : Load sizer generators:
INFO    :   for python
INFO    :   for perl
INFO    :   for lisp
INFO    :   for C++
INFO    :   for XRC
[1]    108065 segmentation fault (core dumped)  wxglade

As you see, segmentation fault happens.
Does anyone have same condition?
Otherwise, does anyone know how to solve it?
Thanks, regards.
